# 'Your credentials did not work' in MS Azure

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I just created an Azure VM using the Windows 8.1 image in the Marketplace. During the creation process I provided a username and password.

After the VM has been created I press connect and try and login via MSTSC - using the credentials that I just entered (with a slash to remove the domain).

But I keep getting 'Your credentials did not work'. What have I done wrong? This procedure has worked for me in the past.

Furthermore, when I review the users of the VM through the portal, I only see 'Subscription admins' containing my Microsoft ID. I can't login using my Microsoft ID either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I don't know why someone downvoted this question. It was legitimate, it also happened to me and I reached this post while trying to find a solution.

Currently I found it. I created a Windows 8.1 VM in Azure and, after providing a username and password, I was getting the 'Your credentials did not work' message when giving them.

I tried some variants and I finally got sucessfull by adding the machine name as the domain (as the user I created is local, it makes sense).

e.g. if your machine is xpto.cloudapps.net, try logging using "xpto\username" as your username.

It worked with me.

Comment: I dunno. But I think using \username converts it to something different than machineName\username, thus a non-working situation as I tested with \username, localhost\username, domain\username and machineName\username. Only the last one worked.

Comment: it works for me, only appears in Windows 8.1 though. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved me after 2 hours of pulling my hair and resetting credentials for 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Domain in the server, you need to login with domain name.

like

domainname\user

That will resolve the issue